# Paramaterize terraform key names?

Tags: terraform, hcl

I'm currently using terraform to write secrets to AWS Secrets Manager and I'm not able to write them via the UI.

I want to be able to parameterize the secret keys. Currently I have written something like this, with the environment

```
 variable "secrets" {
  default = {
    dev_project_db = "database"
    prod_project_db = "database"
    qa_project_db = "database"
  }

  type = map(string)
}
```

Instead I want to do something like this (for when the value is the same between environments)

```
variable "secrets" {
  default = {
    {environment}_{project}_db = "database"
  }

  type = map(string)
}
```

Currently I'm calling it in python like this. Would be nice to shorten the list that I need to write.

```
connection= mysql.connector.connect(host=secrets['{}_{}_host'.format(environment,NAME_OF_PROJECT)],
```

Comment: What are `environment` and `project`?

Comment: You can't have dynamic variables. Instead you should create local variables. Locals can by dynamic.